# Combine materilaized view with query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this query, it runs inside procedure:

```
select sum(mass_mton) as CORR
        from DAY_STREAM_MASS
      where production_day between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR') 
         and LAST_DAY(date_parameter)
         and code = 'CORR'
```

So it sums starting from beginning of year(for selected date parameter
) till last day of month of selected date parameter.
The problem is it runs slow(I have around 15 of such kind of queries in procedure).
So as workaround I created materilized view that 
already calculates sum for each month but doesn't include last previous month, sum of last previous month I want to calculate in query itself since it's updated by user during month closure (they need to see result immediately for last previous month) but everything before last previous month is closed so nobody update it, so mat view looks like below:

```
create materilazed view BALANCE_YEAR
as 
  SELECT TRUNC (production_day, 'month') month,
     SUM (mass_mton) AS volume,
     'CORR' AS code
   FROM DAY_STREAM_MASS
   WHERE     code = 'CORR'
     AND production_day BETWEEN '01-Jan-2011'
     AND ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'month')),-2)
                GROUP BY TRUNC (production_day, 'month')
```

Then I combined mat view with query calculates sum of last previous month:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW BALANCE_YEAR_FINAL
(PRODUCTION_DAY, VOLUME, CODE)
BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS

SELECT "PRODUCTION_DAY", "VOLUME", "CODE" FROM BALANCE_YEAR
UNION
  SELECT TRUNC (production_day, 'month') month,
     SUM (mass_mton) AS volume,
     'CORR' AS code
    FROM DAY_STREAM_MASS
   WHERE     code = 'CORR'
     AND production_day BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'month'), -1)
     AND ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'month')),-1)
GROUP BY TRUNC (production_day, 'month')
```

Now, finally I put it to initial query but select from view created in previous step but it still runs even slow then in my initial query:

```
select sum(mass_mton) as CORR
    from BALANCE_YEAR_FINAL
  where production_day between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR') 
     and LAST_DAY(date_parameter)
     and code = 'CORR'
```

I think the problem here with view so I probably need to avoid using view and use mat view directly with initial query. Is there any way I could combine mat view directly with initial query and use data from mat view and sum of last previous month at the same time or you could do something different in this case?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Some update, I mentioned it runs slower then initial query when select from view, it's true but for first time, when I run the same query for the second time it runs twice faster then initial query so it may cash view for first call and then for second call to view it runs faster so definitelly I need to get rid of using view and use mat view directly with initial query but how to do that I don't know.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when you write `production_day between trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR')` . I gues, the issue lies in this statement,

Comment: trunc(Date_Parameter, 'YEAR') - so it starts calculation from beginning of year, which is Jan 1. So if Date_Parameter  is 12-May-2016 then it starts sum from Jan 1, 2016.